# Azure Storage Read-Only Blob Container

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azure-authentication

I am trying to create a read-only Blob Container with Azure AD Authentication. My application will upload files to this Blob container and an email will be sent to users inside my organization with a link to a file that they will download with a browser.

I have created a simple storage account and created a blob container inside it.
Access level is currently set to: Private (no anonymous access)

I have given my test user **Reader** permission on the Storage Account and **Storage Data Blob Reader** on the blob container

[image]

Permissions given to my demouser account that will only have Reader permissions to blob files:

[image]

I've uploaded a test file with my admin account:

[image]

With my demouser logged into my Azure Organization via Azure Storage Explorer, I can download the file just fine:

[image]

However when I try to download the file with a direct link **https://sareadonly01.blob.core.windows.net/myreadonlycontainer01/TestFile01.txt** from a browser, which will be the way the users will be downloading these files with a link in an email, I get this error: *"The specified resource does not exist."*

[image]

If I change the Access Level of the blob container to: Blob (anonymous read only access for blobs only), then my demouser can download the file in a browser, but so can everyone else outside my organization and this doesn't use AAD Authentication.

[image]
[image]

So how do I create a Read-Only Blob container with AAD Authentication and the ability to download files with a direct URL from a browser?

Comment: when you tried to access from the browser, of course you'll need to add a valid authentication token. Your browser does not do that. Without that, you'll just get a 404

Comment: Shouldn’t it then redirect me to login to Azure when I try to access a file?

Comment: nope it does not do that.

Comment: So this is not possible to setup at all?

Comment: not without some additional component in front of it. Maybe Azure API Management or something could help but that does require setup

Comment: When you try to download the blob via direct link from browser, it does not send the `authorization` header with bearer token, and hence request fails. Tools like Storage explorer use SAS to access, or when using RBAC they send `token` in http header.

Comment: I see now that is not possible to initiate an OAuth from the browser. My impression was that the browser would initiate an OAuth flow to Azure AD to authenticate before being able to download a file.

Comment: @silent Do you have an example of how to use APIM with AAD Authentication and this scenario of downloading blob files from a storage account over a web browser.

Comment: let me see if I can quickly stitch something together

Comment: @silent I am currently googling Azure Front Door. But I am not sure if it has Azure AD Authentication capabilities